# I don't understand why this code is causing a deadlock

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock, synchronized

I'm following the oracle documentation about concurrency, and in the [deadlock section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html) they use the below example. The problem is that I don't quite understand why is this causing a deadlock.

As I see it, that's what I guess it's happening:

- Alphonse bows Gaston and acquires the lock on the `bow` method
- Alphonse leaves the `bow` method and goes into `bowBack`, releasing the first lock and acquiring the second one.
- Gaston repeats the process

But I must be wrong, because if you run the code, it causes a deadlock... what am I missing here?

Thanks a lot!

```java
public class Deadlock
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Friend alphonse = new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston = new Friend("Gaston");

        new Thread(() -> alphonse.bow(gaston)).start();
        new Thread(() -> gaston.bow(alphonse)).start();
    }


    static class Friend
    {
        private final String name;


        Friend(final String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }


        String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }


        synchronized void bow(final Friend bower)
        {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s has bowed to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
            bower.bowBack(this);
        }


        synchronized void bowBack(final Friend bower)
        {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s has bowed back to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's correct @michalk, same issue as here, does I have to mark my question as duplicate or just delete it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say both threads are in `bow` on the `System.out.printf` line. When they try to call `bowBack`, they will both need to acquire a lock on the other instance before `bow` can return and release the locks.

Since both threads are locked, waiting for one another to unlock, this is a deadlock.

Comment: But how is that possible? If `bow` is locked by Alphonse, Gaston cannot enter it, right? That's the thing I don't understand :S

Comment: `synchronized` locks for *one specific instance* of the class, not for all instances of the class. Both people can be within `bow`; there is a separate lock for each of them. See [the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Comment: wow... I'm having serious trouble here understanding concurrency... thanks a lot for your help! I need to digest this new information, because I now don't understand why is this useful for at all... thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> Alphonse leaves the bow method and goes into bowBack, releasing the first lock and acquiring the second one.

There's your issue -- the lock is not released when `bowBack` is called from `bow`, but now you'll need to acquire the lock for the other object, too. The lock would only be released when you *exit* the `bow` method, which only happens after you exit the `bowBack` method called from it.